# Laravel 4 migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

i have created my database , then i have created a table with

```
php artisan migrate: make create_users_table
```

a file has created so i modified up and down function and i typed

```
php artisan migrate
```

until now everything is ok the problem started when i tried to add
 another lignes to my database , i added another information about
 users and when i  type

```
php artisan migrate
```

the response was Nothing to migrate and there is no change into my databse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 possibilities:

1. Create a new migration
2. Rollback the last migration operation and rerun it :

   ```
   php artisan migrate:rollback
   php artisan migrate
   ```
3. Rollback all migrations and run them all again

   ```
   php artisan migrate:refresh
   ```

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/migrations

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another migration, or you can refresh your previous migrations

php artisan migrate:refresh

http://laravel.com/docs/migrations

Answer (score 0):

If you just added more records in a table that already exists using e.g. phpmyadmin, there is no need to run again `php artisan migrate`, because no extra migration is created. That's why you get the "Nothing to migrate" message.

But, if you want for example to add a new column or delete an existing one, the ideal way to do it is by creating a new migration and name it something like `add_columnname_on_users_table`, edit properly the new migration file, then run `php artisan migrate`.